# Alterações no código-fonte são ignoradas pelo compilador

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Eu tenho um pequeno projeto em Delphi 2006, e o migrei para o Delphi XE6. No entanto, a partir desta migração, percebi que as alterações que faço no código fonte, como alterações no título do formulário, mensagens, ou até mesmo em condições lógicas não são incluídas no executável gerado.

Independentemente se uso a opção de *Run Without Debugging*, *Run*, ou *Build*, nenhuma alteração é refletida no executável final. O interessante é que a cada compilação o executável anterior é substituído, e é gerado um executável novo, com data e hora atualizados, e inclusive, se eu mudar o *Output directory*, ele irá gerar o novo executável dentro do novo diretório, mas ainda assim, sem as mudanças que fiz no código.

Exemplo:

[- Aplicativo antes da alteração (Note data e hora do executável).](http://i.share.pho.to/d2c4c7dc_o.png)

[- Alterei o caption.](http://i.share.pho.to/50db09a4_o.png)

[- Inclui uma mensagem no evento create.](http://i.share.pho.to/be054a68_o.png)

[- Compilei, mas continua sem alterações (Data e hora atualizadas).](http://i.share.pho.to/fa573d18_o.png)

Como solucionar este problema?

Comment: essas alterações são feitas nos fontes do próprio projeto ou em alguma bpl do grupo de projetos?

Comment: As alterações estão sendo feitas no próprio projeto, no meu formulário principal.

Comment: E a data de criação/alteração do executável? Como fica? Você pode postar algumas imagens para ilustrar o problema?

Comment: Vou providenciar.

Comment: Imagens incluídas na postagem @Filipe.Fonseca.

Comment: Tire uma dúvida, se for o caso posto a resposta: Você copiou e colou os fontes em outro lugar? Talvez seja o caso de o ufrmMain que você está alterando não pertencer ao projeto RADSMSServer

Comment: Não, @Filipe.Fonseca, peguei o mesmo projeto que estava abrindo no Delphi 2006 e abri no XE6, como é um projeto extremamente pequeno, não precisei fazer mudanças no código para compilar no XE6, compilou tranquilo e salvei, mas depois fui tentar fazer alterações, e percebi este problema.

Comment: Uma última pergunta: Por que você tem 2 ufrmMain abertos?

Comment: Esse outro formulário eu criei quando já estava tentando resolver o problema. Eu percebi o problema quando estava tentando criar uma rotina para mandar o programa para a bandeja do sistema ao minimizar. Como não estava dando certo, criei outro projeto, e neste outro projeto também um frmMain. Como a rotina deu certo no novo projeto eu abri ali esse formulário apenas para comparar os códigos e ver se havia diferença, mas ele não pertence ao projeto e as alterações não estão sendo feitas nele.

Comment: Você mencionou o executável, mas e os arquivos .dcu estão sendo alterados? Você possui mais de uma cópia do código no seu pc?

Comment: @EMBarbosa, de fato, verifiquei no diretório do meu projeto, e apesar de eu estar usando a opção "Build" para recompilar todas as DCU's, aparentemente elas não estavam sendo recompiladas, não sei se devido a problema na migração ou não. Mas uma vez que apaguei as mesmas e o Delphi as recriou, as alterações foram sim para o excutável. Poderia postar como resposta a fim de que eu a aceite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você mencionou o executável, mas e os arquivos .dcu estão sendo alterados? Você possui mais de uma cópia do código no seu pc?

Acontece que o Delphi pode estar utilizando bpls ou arquivos dcus antigos e não estar refazendo todo o trabalho que deveria.